# scrollTop not working on IE but ok on chrome

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I use this js and works great on chrome:

```
$('#main-nav a').click( function() {
                event.preventDefault();
                var nome = $(this).attr("href");

                 $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $(nome).offset().top-198
     }, 1600);


});
```

But doesn't work at all on IE, dont scroll or anything, just goes down to the target div without the offset... any helps?
I use `<!DOCTYPE html>`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't passed the `event` object to the function:

```
$('#main-nav a').click(function(event) {
```